# Updating a self-contained application

Tags: qt, updates, auto-update

I have a self-contained application built against a static Qt library. One of the requirements is to update itself.

**How updating is done:**
To do this, it checks the application version against a web API and downloads update from a API link from a remote server.

There is a [post](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338180/how-to-update-self-contained-asp-net-core-app-and-avoid-file-locks&ved=2ahUKEwjvuaXZrejkAhXHSxUIHck2D0EQjjgwDHoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0oJJ0nmpyfP9STmU0H-6ur) that asks this question but doesn't provide useful information to my problem, or in general how to update an application.

How do I update a self-contained executable?

Comment: @eyllanesec this is good, but since my app is a standalone self-contained app, the method of using a installation based framework will unfortunately not help. I am thinking of a powershell based updater script which is run as a separate process to update the app itself (the exe), but I am not sure if this is a good method.

Comment: The general logic of the self-update is: 1) download the new executable 2) launch the new executable 3) close the current application

Comment: [WinSparkle](https://winsparkle.org/) is a good solution. You need scripts to uninstall current version and installing new after download ...  if you interested in automating everything with standard tools  [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) is a good combination with WinSparkle

Comment: Which platforms should the application run on?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld my application is Windows specific, but I would prefer a solution applicable to any desktop OS (or as far as possible a generic solution)